# Store a redirect URI for use after login

Tags: redirect, login

I need to pass the current page's URI into either the HTTP headers or as a URL query string so that after being taken to the login page and successfully logging in, the user will be sent back to where they came from.

I think that by attaching a query to any login button around the site I can then tell the login page where to go. The Login button is part of many of my templates / partials show when conditionally displaying content depending on if user is logged in.

By using `<a href="members/login?p={% craft.request.path %}">`

For example I thought that:

```
{% if craft.request.getQuery('p') and craft.request.getQuery('p')|length %}
    {% set p = craft.request('p') %}
{% else %}
    {% set p = '/' %}
{% endif %}
```

would set me up to redirect if the url contains `http://craft.fira/members/login?p=/members/directory/json`. However that results in a 404. Is there a safe way to pass a path into a url query?

Secondly, I then need to know how to deal with this after logging in successfully.

All help greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First – your Twig syntax is a little off. Here's how you could add the current URL/request path to a link, as a query parameter `p`:

```
<a href="members/login?p={{ craft.request.path }}">Log in</a>
```

Notice that the syntax/tag for printing a value/variable is `{{ value }}`, not `{% value %}`.

Second, since the redirect in this case should happen when the login form is successfully submitted, it makes sense to add the redirect URL to the form as a `redirect` input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ craft.request.getQuery('p')|default('/') }}" />
```

*Note that `craft.request` should be all lowercase; in Craft almost all variables or service names follow the `camelCase` naming convention (the `craft.request` variable refers to the [`HttpRequestVariable`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/variables/HttpRequestVariable) class, which wraps the [`HttpRequestService`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService)).*

Additionally, the above example demonstrates use of the `default` filter, which will print the declared value (in this case, `/`) if the value preceding the `default` statement is `null` or `false`. In this case, using `default` will save you an `if` statements and several lines of code.

Finally, if you want to do a (conditional) redirect outside of a form submission, you can make use of Twig's `redirect` tag:

```
{% set redirectUrl = craft.request.getQuery('p') %}
{% if redirectUrl %}
    {% redirect redirectUrl %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I'd like to add that there is another way of doing this without the URL query. Simply using: `{% set redirect = craft.request.getUrlReferrer() %}` `<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ redirect }}" />` on the login page will get the URL referrer (the previous page that linked to the login page). Thus making the process work when a content editor links to the login page manually without the URL query.

Comment: Or even more succinctly... `<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ craft.request.getUrlReferrer()|default('/') }}" />`

Comment: ...or `value="{{ craft.request.getQuery('p')|default(craft.request.getUrlReferrer()|default('/')) }}"` :P